# Weform: Send email to the email field in the node reference field using rules

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

I have content type `Organiser`. and it has an email field `Organiser email`.

I have created a webform and added a node reference component which is referencing the `Organiser` content type.

I want to send an email on webform submission to the email address entered in the `Organiser email` in referenced node.

Is it possible with rules without entering the php code in the rules action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some work around to get this functionality.

Created a `hidden component` to the webform.

Then through `hook_form_alter`, get the organiser email from the `referenced node` and set it as the default value to that hidden field.

Then in the webform email settings, I selected that hidden webform component as the "`Email to address`".